# Send an image to an API in a Nuxt project

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to send an image in a formData to a Ruby API in a Nuxt Project, I tried several things but none worked.

## In the client side I try this :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', document.getElementById('image_upload').files[0])

const url = await useFetch('/api/post/image', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    body: formData 
})
```

## In the server side I try this :

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

    const { APIPassword, APIUrl } = useRuntimeConfig()

    const { token } = await $fetch(`${APIUrl}/token/${APIPassword}`)

    const image = await readBody(event)

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('image', image)

    console.log(formData)

    const url = await $fetch(`${APIUrl}/image`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-CSRF-Token': token
        },
        body: formData
    })

    return url
})
```

## In Python this code is working well

```
import requests

url = "http://api.example.com/image"
headers = {}

files = {'image': open('image/image.png', 'rb')}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```